# where to keep my frontend js file while using node?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

i have made a todo list using html css and js. Now i want a backend to store my items in a database. At this stage where do i store my js file which i have created along with html and css. I have placed it in public folder and out of public folder as well but it is not working as i run server. My todo list is not performing functionality neither adding , deleting or editing. These three function are which i have created in js file.

[image]

Comment: Maybe is `./src/js/`?

Comment: is your server code in index.js? If so, that is the code we need to see. Not app.js

Comment: yes my server code is in index.js

Comment: kindly help.....

Comment: we need to see your server code. You need to enable the public folder to serve the files rather than interpret them with node. You can do this in a few lines using the `express` framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm install express` in your root directory

In the `index.js` file at the root of you project:

```
// Use the express framework to speed things up
const express = require('express');

// Create an app instance which you will use to start your server
const app = express();
// Use a constant for which Port you want to start your server on
const port = 3000;

// HERE IS THE STUFF TO MAKE THE PUBLIC DIRECTORY SERVE STATIC FILES
// app.use(urlPath, middleware) - execute middleware when urlPath is requested
// express.static(filepath) - Is a pre-packaged middleware that will serve
// the contents of the filepath as static files
// '/public' says visit: 'http://localhost:3000/public' to view the contents
// of the directory
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// if running on your localhost the you will see the 
// below message if you visit http://localhost:3000
// after starting your server 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World, my server is up and running!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Now your server is setup to server static files from your `public` directory.

Start the server by running `node index.js` from within your root directory. Open your browser and visit `http://localhost:3000` and you should see the message `Hello World, my server is up and running!`.

Navigate to `http://localhost:3000/public` and you should see the contents of you public directory.

Navigate to `http://localhost:3000/public/<fileName>` and you should see the contents of the specific file or image.